# is there any open source application like google code hosted in local server?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, web-applications, open-source

I'd like to setup such application in my company to host some small projects/tools, should have small wiki, source control integrated(svn,git...), bug track, summary..

Answer (score 4):

- [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) (Python)
- [Traq](http://traqproject.org/) (PHP)
- [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) (Ruby/Rails)

Comment: + for Redmine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Su's Answer.

There [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) by Facebook.